# How to refresh tag list in org-mode without closing and reopening emacs

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In my emacs org-mode org file I have a tag list

```
#+TAGS: OFFICE(o) COMPUTER(c) HOME(h) PROJECT READING(r) PHOTOGRAPHY(p)
```

At some point, I wish to add a new tag to the list, and apply it to an item (using `C-c C-c`). But the new tag does not show up in the list of selectable tags.

In order to fix this, I close and reopen emacs. But I'm sure that isn't necessary, How do I refresh this list without restarting emacs?

Comment: are they todo tags which you set with `#+TODO: ` or category tags which you set with `#+FILETAGS:` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `C-c C-c` on the top of the org file. It updates the local config of the file.

Comment: For me, it prompts for a tag to apply to the item on the first line of the file. If I insert an empty line and type `C-c C-c` there, I get `'C-c C-c' can do nothing useful here` (I'm trying to refresh after customizing `org-tag-alist`.)

Answer (score 0):

One way to force a refresh of tags in a buffer after customizing `org-tag-alist` is `M-x org-mode-restart`. The side effect is that all nested trees are folded, so you may lose track of what you were working on in the buffer.